# Help identifying this damaged FFC/FPC connector

Tags: connector, identification, repair, fpc, ffc

I am trying to identify this damaged connector on one of the PCBs of a Konica Minolta Vivid 910 laser 3D scanner. I wish to find a suitable match for replacement.

It connects the main logic board with the LCD via a **FFC cable**. (The LCD itself has a small board and connector also, although I don't believe the two are the same connector).

The connector has **33pins**, and I'm pretty confident it has a **pitch of 0.5mm**.

[image: unkown 33pin 0.5mm pitch FFC/FPC connector]

The connector width is 20mm from side to side. Although the front facing corners are damaged so it could have been marginally wider.

[image]

I am uncertain of the contact orientation however. I seem to see two sets of matching rows, with the lower apparently protruding slightly more. However the FFC cable only has contacts on one side, suggesting the connector would not be dual contact.

From the photos, I'm inclined to think it is a bottom contact connector.

[image]
[image]

On this photo you can see the FFC end is one sided, and you can also see the dark grey tab/drawer which now does not fit the connector. Pay no attention to the tape botch-job. It was painful to watch, and I'm not sure about the orientation it's presenting the cable in is correct.

[image]

For reference here are two photos of the connector on the LCD side.
I believe it is substantially different, especially the big dark grey flap tab.

[image]
[image]

I do not have immediate access to this board, as it is in my university, but could recheck facts in the near future if needed.

So, to recap: I believe I am looking for a 33pin 0.5mm pitch, probably bottom contact, FFC connector. I am unsure if the clamping mechanism was a flip tap or a drawer tab.
I am also wondering if it matters either way. Since I am replacing the connector can I not basically match pitch and pin numbers and accommodating for cable orientation select any clamping method that seems reasonably adequate?

In any case, matching the original connector would be nice.

I don't think its a complete match but the closest I've got is this Hirose Connector:
FH12-33S-0.5SH(55)

https://www.mouser.es/ProductDetail/Hirose-Connector/FH12-33S-05SH55?qs=Ux3WWAnHpjB322do3zzp5w==

Let me know what you all think. Thank you very much for the help.

P.S.#2
Also, is 33pins an uncommon number of contacts for FPC/FFC? I seem to find less results with 33pins.

Comment: Well, I've searched the Digikey and found only one FFC connector with double-sided contacts: [XF3M-3315-1B](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/omron-electronics-inc-emc-div/XF3M-3315-1B/Z5262CT-ND/5251106) from Omron. This is a back-lock type, and I'm not sure if it really fits to your needs. I especially searched the products with double-sided contacts, because you are not sure if the FFC cable's contacts are touching the top side or the bottom side. If you are really sure they touch to the bottom then the one that you linked in your question is a hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a Hirose connector, I'm 99% sure (that's before I saw the link in the post). Model # FH12A-33S-0.5SH(55)

See if you can sample one from Hirose directly.

On yours, I think the sides that retain the latch got ripped off somehow

[image]
Source: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/FH12A-33S-0-5SH-55/HFK133TR-ND/1110336

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation Voltage Spike. I am glad you found that top contact variant.
It makes sense with the current cable orientation, I think. And that last photo looks very close to what I have. (I believe the sides got ripped off indeed, probably when my boss and I first disassembled it.) Have written to Hirose to try and source a sample from them.
Thanks again!